# Switching Persistence Framework after implementation?

Tags: java, hibernate, frameworks, persistence

When design a system that uses a persistence framework (PF) to store and retrieve information from a database, say for example Hibernate, *how important is it in the planning phase to choose a suitable framework?*

Say for example that you find a more suitable PF later in development, would a switch require mayor rewrites in the entire system or would it be possible to contain the changes to the service-layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the persistence framework is always a big effort, but you can use [the DAO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) to insulate the UI and business model of your system from those changes, and reduce the amount of code required for a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

In future if you need to switch to another PF it will require major change in the application.So you can use JPA right now so later you need to do small change in the application code.